# Django: Error matching query does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Este código me arroja el error:

> matching query does not exist

Al parecer el filtro que he diseñado no me captura el id de los Pedidos.

Código:

```
models.py:

class Pedido(models.Model):
    especialidad   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    articulo       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
    fecha_entrega  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    fecha_pedido   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,     blank=True)
    cantidad       = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    pendiente      = models.CharField(max_length=999,  null=True, blank=True)
    estado         =  models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='pendiente')

views.py 

def ArticuloListView(request, id_especialidad):
  user = request.user
  if user.is_superuser:
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)  #filtro de error
  else:
    pedido = Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad__encargado__usuario=user.id)
    template  = 'index2.html'
    return render_to_response(template,locals(), Context)
```

Aquí la url:(esta si captura el id seleccionado)

```
url(r'^lista_esp/(?P<id_especialidad>\d+)/$', ArticuloListView, name="listar_esp"),
```

No sé como crear un filtro adecuado para lo que se requiere. ¿Alguna ayuda por favor? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta usando el botón `{}` para formatear el código. Te recomiendo que sigas esta guía [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que dice el error es que la consulta no tiene resultados.

Como siempre existe ese riesgo, Django ofrece un atajo llamado [`get_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) que manda a los usuarios a la página de error.

Por supuesto, puedes capturar la excepción (con `try`y `catch`) que se lanza y que es de tipo [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#doesnotexist), para darle otro tratamiento.

Comment: muy bien, y usted sabe que puede siginificar este error y como tratarlo?The view Pedidoapp.views.ArticuloListView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @DemaroCreate si tienes alguna pregunta, por favor crea tu propia publicación.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es obtener un sólo resultado del queryset

```
pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
```

Si bien puedes hacer lo que indica Angel puedes también manejarlo con .first() de modo que cuando sea un queryset vacío devolverá None y no un error como el que indicas.

```
pedido = Pedido.objects.filter(id=id_especialidad).first()
```

De todas formas va a depender de lo que quieras hacer, sería mejor manejar la vista que sólo reciba post y no puedan modificar ese dato desde navegador. La idea de usar get_object_or_404 es buena, pero depende de lo que quieras.

```
 pedido = get_object_or_404(Pedido, id=id_especialidad)
```

Answer (score 0):

El origen de tu error esta en que el id que estas tratando de consultar no existe en BD

`pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)`

para evitar esto, y mas cuando el id esta siendo recibido desde la url, te recomiendo hacer un paso previo de verificación, como por ejemplo:

```
if Pedido.objects.filter(id=id_especialidad).exists():
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
    # resto de acciones cuando el pedido existe
else:
    # acciones cuando el pedido no existe, redireccionas, envias un mensaje o cualquier opcion que consideres necesario para tratar este caso
    pass
```

Y asi evitar a que cualquier id que no existe rompa la aplicacion

Saludos